# Added log4j to class path and still getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jvm, log4j

I added the following to my class path:

```
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
```

But still I get an error. The exception starts with :

```
Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4/Level
```

What's wrong here? Any light you can shed into this, would be very helpful.

Comment: You need to add log4j-1.2.16.jar [http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not having Log4j jar in class path add `log4j-1.2.15.jar` to classpath

Answer (score 2):

You need to add log4j implementation to your classpath, because what you currently have is slf4j facade and slf4j bridge to log4j, but not log4j itself.